# Arduino analog only reading 40 when grounded

Tags: arduino

As the title suggests, I am trying to work out why my Arduino won't go lower than around 40 on the analog pin scale when that pin is simply grounded.

Could it be interference (it's part of a breadboard circuit)?

I've tried both analog pins 0 and 1 with same result, printing to serial.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: **It was not interference as such, but a poor breadboard connection to ground, and once connected more direct it reads 0 again in its full circuit.**

Ok, I should have done this test first before posting my question, but I just put another new Arduino on a board by itself and it is reading 0, so it must be interference, or that board. Though I think it will be interference due to all the other wiring for a 2 line LCD.

```
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  Serial.println(analogRead(0));
  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: ok, it was definitely interference, i took the original board out and tested it by itself and its fine.... now to work out the interference...